# C++ Changing a decimal to octal, output backwards

Tags: c++, decimal, octal

So I wrote this small application that will convert a decimal to octal, and it is outputting the right answer only it's backwards. An example would be that if the answer to the conversion was 17, the application would display it as 71. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
;
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
int octal, total = 0;
    cout<< "please enter a decimal: ";
    cin >> octal;
    while(octal > 0)
    {
                total = octal % 8;
        octal /= 8;
        cout << total;
    }
    cout << endl;
        _getche(); 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays (Possible Solution #1) or recursive functions (Possible Solution #2)? A rather bad solution would be to store the output in a string and reverse that ("bad" because there are better ways).

Comment: Why are strings worse than arrays? It is almost the same

Comment: @Machtl: *almost* the same. With a string you can use the library function `strrev` or write your own. Using an array, you are not using a library function, you are programming "closer to the metal". You don't even have to *physically* reverse the array. As this seems exercise, rather than production code, I'd not go for a library function -- the same applies to "printf using `%o`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a sum and then print the final result, something like

```
int n=0;
while (octal > 0) {
  total += (pow(10,n++))*(octal % 8);
  octal /= 8;
}
cout << total << endl;
```

Just printing the digits will print them in reverse order since you are printing the smallest bits first.

As noted in the comments, the mechanism above will only work for converting to bases smaller than 10.

Comment: Did'nt you forget to `octal /= 8`? Otherwise the loop will never stop

Comment: Nice solution, but this *converts* the input to a decimal notation. The same algorithm would not work for hexadecimal.

Comment: Typing faster than my mental code writer could follow...  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Can I ask what the expt is?

Comment: @user2970001: it is the function that returns the value of 10 to the power n.  I forget, the name of that function might actually be `pow` in C++...

Answer (score 4):

You can use std::oct to print number in octal notation.

```
int n = 123;
std::cout << std::oct << n << std::endl;
```

Similarly you can print number in different notations like decimal - `std::dec` and hexadecimal - `std::hex`.

Those input/output manipulators allow user to parse string numbers in various notations.

```
int n;
std::istringstream("24") >> std::hex >> n;
std::cout << n << std::endl;  // n is 36 (decimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine but you have to print the remainders in reverse order to get the correct answer . For e.g.  if ans is 17 then decimal equivalent will be 1*8^1+7*8^0 . unit digit will be the remainder obtained by dividing the number by 8 , next digit to the left will be the remainder obtained by dividing the number by 8^2 and so on. So if the number in octal is of n digit then the most significant digit will be the remainder obtained by dividing the number by 8^n.That is why you have to print the remainder in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using an array for temporary storage:

```
int octal, total = 0, length=0;
char storage[12];   /* 11 octal digits add up to > 1 billion */
octal = 123;
while (octal > 0)
{
  storage[length] = octal % 8;
  octal /= 8;
  length++;
}
while (--length >= 0)
  printf ("%d", storage[length]);
printf ("\n");
```

(I happened to be in C mode, hence the `printf`s. Change to `cout` where required.)

The most important point is that you are bound by the `storage` size. You can set it to a *reasonable* size -- the largest positive octal size you can put in an integer is `017777777777` --, and even an *unreasonable* size is acceptable (you can set it to 20, which will only waste 8 additional bytes; these days, that's *nothing*). The storage size is determined by how big the *representation* of your number is in octal, for the largest number you can enter.

Suppose you change both `8`s to `2`; then you can use this same routine for binary output. But at that point, the number of output characters increases to 31! (One less than the [likely] number of bits in your `int`, because the last bit would toggle the number to *negative*. You need separate code to handle negative numbers.)

It works as-is for all bases <=10 (including "base 10" itself). If you want to extend the same code to handle bases >10, such as "duodecimal" (base 12) or hexadecimal (base 16), you need to change the `printf` line. This will make your code work up to base 36 ("sexatrigesimal"). Per convention, "digits" higher than 9 are written A,B,C and so on:

```
while (--length >= 0)
  printf ("%c", storage[length] < 10 ? storage[length]+'0' : storage[length]+'A'-10);
```

(As I'm making this up as I write, I used the *ternary* operator `?..:..` for convenience, rather than a separate `if..else`, which needs more typing. (OTOH, adding the comment negates the gain. Oh well -- at least you learned about the ternary operator, as well as the names for a couple of number bases.))

---

Another solution is to use *recursion*. This is a useful method because it doesn't need to preallocate some space in memory -- instead, it relies on the internal call stack.

The principle is that you write a function that only prints the last digit of your number -- but *before* it does that, unless the remainder is 0, it calls *itself* with the *remainder* of the number.

So the function calls itself, then prints the number it should. Because it first calls itself, the *called* version prints the number it should -- the one *to the left* of the digit in the "original" function. And so on and so forth, until there is no digit remaining to be printed. From that point on, the last called function prints its number (which is the leftmost digit), returns to the function it was called from, which in turn prints *its* number (one more to the right), all the way down to the original call.

Recursion is a pretty cool skill to master, so do try this!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two handy functions which might be useful. They return string for each of the conversions. On similar lines to igleyy's answer.

```
string toOctalFromDecimal (int num) {
    ostringstream o;
    o << std::oct << num;
    return o.str();
}

string toDecimalFromOctal (int num) {
    std::ostringstream o;
    int x;

    std::istringstream(to_string(num)) >> std::oct >> x;
    o << std::dec << x;
    return o.str();
}
```